# Loop with density lines in different colors in R

Tags: for-loop

I'm trying to create a loop to plot several different lines in different colors. I know this could be easily done using `ggplot2` and I've used it a lot in the past, but now `ggplot2` is giving me some extra lines that shouldn't be there.

I tried a lot of different combinations to create a new variable for color or an extra loop inside, but just could not solve this. The best I got so far was to have all lines with the same color (red, or green), but that's useless.
This is the code I'm using. I'd like to get a different color for each `var2`.
Thanks!

```
a <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.5, sd=1),
                 var2=c("a"))
b <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.6, sd=1.1),
            var2=c("b"))
c <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.7, sd=1.2),
            var2=c("c"))
mydata<-data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))

y<-unique(mydata$var2)

plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(0, 0.5))
for (i in y){
  lines(density(mydata$var1[mydata$var2==i]))}
```

[image: density plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out how to solve this. I'll post here in case someone else needs it.
First, create a new variable with a color for each var2:

```
a <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.5, sd=1),
                 var2=c("a"))
a$color<-c("#FF0000FF")
```

Then assign a color for each curve:

```
col=mydata$color[mydata$var2==i]
```

The final code I got is this:

```
a <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.5, sd=1),
                 var2=c("a"))
a$color<-c("#FF0000FF")
b <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.6, sd=1.1),
            var2=c("b"))
b$color<-c("#00FF00FF")
c <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(500, m=0.7, sd=1.2),
            var2=c("c"))
c$color<-c("#0000FFFF")
mydata<-data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))

y<-unique(mydata$var2)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(0, 0.5))
for (i in y){
  lines(density(mydata$var1[mydata$var2==i]),col=mydata$color[mydata$var2==i])}
```

Hope it helps someone